# Open http://www.youtube.com inside jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I am trying to open youtube website inside a jquery ui dialog, the code is very simple

```
 <div>
<iframe src='http://youtube.com' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>
</div>
```

this div is being generated programtically, the issue is only youtube is not opening up other websites are opening properly

Comment: but it could be releated (it isn't) with jquery's plugin preventing iframes from showing or something ;)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube has iframe protection to protect fake views etc. It's bad but that'S a fact

Comment: yep. same with a lot of other big sites

Comment: @genesis only if you have allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" attribute added